# how to retrieve selenium webdriver sessionid using unittest framework?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to retrieve the session id of a selenium webdriver session during the execution of a test as such:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def testSomething(self):
        """selenium tests go here"""
        self.driver.get('http://www.example.com')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest)
    testResult = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    session_id = ???
```

I know I could do self.driver.session_id side the setUp method. The problem is I need to get the session id outside of the class instance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can create property/function inside the class instance which could return you sessionID.